# Who determines which are the trusted authorities that are in the default java keystore?

Tags: java, applet, keystore

We are having issues with a client's certificate, and one of the intermediate authorities are not on the authorized list  for java applets.  One solution is to get a new certificate, but how are we to know that the intermediate authorities will not change later?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions.  There are other stackexchange.com sites that are more appropriate for system-administrator type questions like this.  I'm thinking either serverfault.com or superuser.com--anyone else have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the intermediate authority certificate and add it to your keystore. While adding the cert, you can mark it as trusted. Here is the command to add the cert to keystore:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file intermediate.crt -alias intermediateCA -keystore  $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

As part of this import you will be asked something like this:

```
Trust this certificate?
```

Just enter yes and you should be good.

To grab all the certificate in the chain, you can use this command:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect yourURL:443
```